# Jquery cant find "this" within a if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am using jquery and wanted to use an if statement to determine the width of a span and if it's larger than x with add a class to the  same object

```
if ($(".tool-tip").width() > 300) {
$(this).addClass("full-width")
}
```

I expected "this" to apply a class of full-with to the class of tool-top

Comment: well an if statement does not scope the this.... so you are applying it to something else. Simple console.log(this) will show that.

Comment: that doesnt work like that as @epascarello already mentioned - here's a [good read](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) on how to add classes with jquery ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `this` doesn't change within a given function context, but you can take advantage of a variation jQuery provides for the `.width()` method:

```
$(".tool-tip").width(function(index, width) {
  if (width > 300)
    $(this).addClass("full-width");
});
```

That will operate on *every* element with class "tool-tip"; if you just want to affect the first one, as your sample code would (if it worked), you can check the `index` parameter, which tells you the index into the list of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `this` refers to the containing function. It can be used in jQuery in the following context:

```
$(".tool-tip").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("full-width");
})
```

In your case, you would need to use the identifier again, i.e.

```
if ($(".tool-tip").width() > 300) {
    $(".tool-tip").addClass("full-width");
}
```

Edit:
Also, the selector will return multiple items. You can iterate over them as Pointy showed, or you can just pick the first occurrence using `$(".tool-tip").eq(0)` instead of `$(".tool-tip")`

Answer (score 0):

`this` is function scoped meaning that it will only hold a different value if inside of a function.  If you call `this` outside of any function, `this` refers to the `Window` itself.  Calling `this` from inside a function refers to the function itself unless you are calling `this` from an `Event` in which case `this` refers to the element that caused the event to trigger.  In your case, if the `if` statement you have is not within a function, `this` will refer to the `Window`.